# Replacing a value in a string - Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my application in angular I have a string of the type:

"Word §Variable§ word §Variable§ word"

and via three mat-selects the user can choose a word to replace '§Variable§' in one of the three positions. (The string and the number of variables can change, so I have to create a dynamic function that can change each time according to the number of '§Variable§' within the sentence.)

I created this function (I have entered the string as static, just to make the function clearer here on Stackoverflow):

```
replace(variationNumber: number, value: string){    
  /*VariationNumber is the position of '§Variable§' that I have to replace*/
  /*Value is the value the user has chosen via mat-select*/  
  let text= 'Word §Variable§ word §Variable§ word';
  let search = '§Variable§'
  text = text.replace(RegExp("^(?:.*?"+search+"){" + (variationNumber) + "}"), function(x){return x.replace(RegExp(search + "$"), value)});
}
```

When the value of §Variable§ has been replaced and the user via mat-select selects another value instead of the one already present, the value is not replaced (because there is no longer §Variable§ inside the string, but the value that the user had previously selected), how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to keep the template and the output separate. The moment you replace a placeholder in your template, all placeholders after that are suddenly one position earlier.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, exactly, in fact I have also tried saving the model in another variable and replacing it each time, only when the user selects a different mat-select the selected one changes correctly, but all others are reset and return "§Variable§".

Comment: So then you need to keep track of requested replacements in a variable, as well.

Comment: so I should create an array that has all the user's chosen options inside and each time I go and update this array with the user's selection and then go and replace it in the original string?

Comment: @Cerbrus the problem with creating an array that keeps track of user choices is that on the same page I might have several different blocks of text with n variables inside, so I would have to create an array of arrays, and I wanted to find a simpler, more straightforward solution

Comment: I've submitted an answer. I'm not sure there's a more straightforward solution available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out.

With a simplified regex, you can iterate over all the placeholders, and replace them with a specified value:

```js
const replacements = [];
const template = 'Word §Variable§ word §Variable§ word';

function replace(variationNumber, value) {
  /*VariationNumber is the position of '§Variable§' that I have to replace*/
  /*Value is the value the user has chosen via mat-select*/
  let text = template;
  let search = '§Variable§';
  
  // Store the requested replacement in an array,
  // overwriting older ones if the number is the same.
  replacements[variationNumber] = value; 

  replacements.forEach((value, index) => {
    let i = 0; // Track current replacement index
    text = text.replace(RegExp(search, 'g'), () => {
        ++i;
        // Return the replacement value for the current index, or the placeholder if one isn't set.
        return replacements[i] ?? search;
    })
  })
  
  return text;
}

console.log(replace(1, 'foo'));
console.log(replace(2, 'bar'));
console.log(replace(1, 'baz'));

console.log(replacements);
```